# MySQL query to match dates and times placed in separate columns

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, join

I have two tables

```
------------------------
|   Vehicles           |
------------------------
+ id                   +
| name                 |
+ available_from_date  +
| available_from_time  |
+ available_to_date    +
| available_to_time    |
-----------------------


------------------------
|   Reserved_Vehicles  |
------------------------
+ id                   +
| vehicle_id           |
+ reserved_from_date   +
| reserved_from_time   |
+ reserved_to_date     +
| reserved_to_time     |
-----------------------
```

I want to query vehicles table such that I get only those vehicles which meet the availability date and time and also not already reserved for that time.

For example, I want to search vehicles which are available FROM date 2012-07-27 & time 10:00 TO date 2012-08-15 & time 14:00.

How to solve above problem with one query?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I tried in following way but it gives wrong results


SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE 
(available_from_date <= "07/27/2012" AND available_from_time <=" 9:00:00" ) AND (
available_to_date >= "07/31/2012" AND available_to_time >= "9:00:00")

Comment: But you even need to check the reserved dates right or they doesn't matter to you?

Comment: Why not store the to and from fields as `DATETIME` types. This will make things a whole lot easier for you as you will have access to many robust date manipulation and comparison functions.

Comment: SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Reserved_Vehicles) AND (available_from_date <= "07/27/2012" AND available_from_time <=" 9:00:00" ) AND ( available_to_date >= "2012-08-14" AND available_to_time >= "10:00:00")

this query excludes the available vehicle because of time check as the time in query is 10:00:00 not 09:00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could just use AND in your WHERE clause. Is that not working?

Do you need to query both tables? Or can you safely assume that if a car is reserved at a given time then it's not available, and if it's available then it's not reserved?

Comment: i tried SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Reserved_Vehicles) AND (available_from_date <= "07/27/2012" AND available_from_time <=" 9:00:00" ) AND ( available_to_date >= "07/31/2012" AND available_to_time >= "9:00:00")

BUT the problem arise when I switch between time say a vehicle is available to 2012-08-15 at 09:00 and I search with above query

Comment: SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM Reserved_Vehicles) AND (available_from_date <= "07/27/2012" AND available_from_time <=" 9:00:00" ) AND ( available_to_date >= "2012-08-14" AND available_to_time >= "10:00:00")

this query excludes the available vehicle because of time check as the time in query is 10:00:00 not 09:00:00.

Comment: The time variable is only relevant if the day is equal to the day you're testing for. If it's available from an earlier day or available to a later day, then the time is irrelevant. So you need to test for ((available_from_date = day AND available_from_time <= time) OR (available_from_date < day))